# Problem printing with V6 hotend on Creality Ender 3

Tags: creality-ender-3, e3d-v6, direct-drive

I have installed V6 hotend (all metal) with a direct drive extruder on Ender 3. It flows alright when I push manually however, the print is severely under extruded and doesn't stick to the bed.

Things I have already tried:

- Replaced the nozzle and the heat break however, the problem persists.
- Tried changing the filament. PETG wrecked the heat break. PLA doesn't print either.
- Reduced the retracing to 0.3 mm
- Cleaning the bed.

[image]

Comment: Have you calibrated the extruder?